# C# TreeView - AfterSelect Event firing unwanted

Tags: c#, events, triggers, event-handling, treeview

i have a little Problem with my treeview.

Background: I have a treeview with multiple Items in it, whenever you click on a Parent or first child an Event should fire where a new window opens where you can do some stuff.

I am using the "After_Select" event of the tree view as following:

```
 if (_inside) //this boolean was my first attempt to deal with the problem
        {
                if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent != null)
                {
                    if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Parent != null)
                    {
                        //its 2nd child -> do nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Configuration_New_Click(treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Name.ToString(), treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString()); //its 1st child do something
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Configuration_New_Click(treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString(), ""); //its parent, do something else
                }
        }
```

The Problem: The Event fires everytime i for example tab out of the program and tab back in -> the first item in the treeview gets selected -> AfterSelect fires. I have some more situations like this, basically the event does what it should, it fires whenever an item was selected. The problem is the first treeview item gets selected whenever the treeview looses focus by switching windows for example. (it only fires if i clicked a other treeview item than the first before doing so)

I read a bit in the forum and found a solution i tried -> set a boolean to false whenever it should not trigger. it works with some Problems but the event still triggers when i alt+tab to other windows and alt tab back to back programm. is there any quick and dirty solution to handle this?

Thanks for your time and effort!

Edit: Is the "MouseDown" a better solution? and if so, how can i use this event with my code? since i need the selectedNode in order to run the code above?

Regards,

Christian

Comment: How about `SelectedItemChanged`?

Comment: This Event does not exist in the treeview menus. but even if added it wouldn´t solve the problem since it would trigger at least 1 time anyway, okay not unlimited times but yeah =/ I could add another item as first item where no event triggers and move all other 1 stage back -> parent = 1. child  1.child= 2nd  and 2nd child= 3rd child but that would be a real ugly solution =/

Comment: It does exist https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. I don't understand why it wouldn't solve your problem.

Comment: Oh it appears its just not in winforms, anyway becuse this event fires whenever a SelectedItemChanged the problem is when i click for example on menustrip item 3  and alt+tab to other windows and then alt+tab back in to my programm, the treeview automatically selects the first item in its list -> the selecteditemchanged event will trigger here without the user clicking purposly on an item =/

Comment: The problem is that whenever i switch windows and get back to my programm the TreeView gains focus automatically, and AutoSelects the first item. I tried setting the tabindex higher and the tabstop to none but this does not work =/

Comment: This is so weird. Whenever i clicked on 2nd Child and then Alt+Tab the Bug does NOT appear - the 2nd child just keeps the SelectionMode active but whenever i click on a 1. Child and then alt+tab the 1. child looses control and the first item in treeview gains focus ?! why is that any ideas?